# Xamarin.Forms iOS IdentityServer4 Login Redirect Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm attempting to setup a login with XamarinForms (4.1.x) and iOS (12.x) using IdentityServer (hybrid flow). I'm using the Xamarin Forms iOS example found [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/XamarinForms/XamarinFormsClient/XamarinFormsClient.iOS) as a reference. After I enter my credentials, the browser tries to redirect and I get the follow error:

[image]

I'm not sure what `address` is invalid as nothing appears to be logged. Has anyone successfully used Xamarin.Forms with IdentityServer4 for authentication?

Comment: Make sure you are defining the redirect url schemes properly "RedirectUri = "xamarinformsclients://callback" you have to define that Scheme in infoplist file too!

Comment: @NirmalSubedi that was it. I didn't configure my CFBundleURLSchemes in Info.plist. If you want to submit that answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's the redirect issue to your app.
Make sure you are defining the redirect url schemes properly "RedirectUri = "xamarinformsclients://callback" you have to define that Scheme in infoplist file too!

Answer (score 0):

How people should answer for that kind of question:

You should use Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.your.app</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>xamarinformsclients</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

com.your.app is you bundle app

xamarinformsclients is your  part of your      RedirectUris = { "xamarinformsclients://callback" },